# docker-machine env default | eval "$(docker-machine env default)" | unable to run command docker

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I've tried on Windows 10, windows 7 and Mac OSX, everything went well, but I am unable to run `docker` command after run `docker-machine env default` and `eval "$(docker-machine env default)"` I don't get any error messages.

```
$ docker-machine version
docker-machine version 0.8.2, build e18a919
```

env default

```
$ docker-machine env default
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.78.120:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/elo/.docker/machine/machines/default"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

connect to virtualbox machine

```
$ eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

then I run

```
$ docker
```

**command not found: docker**

I tried windows 10, windows 7 and Mac, just can't communicate with Virtualbox machine, so no docker command is found

I am able to `ssh default`

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: docker command is different than docker-machine command. you should check your $PATH to see if the docker executable is available. whereis docker may also help.

Comment: Thanks `whereis docker` returns empty, I am using osx.  `$ eval "$(docker-machine env default)"` doesn't make my shell communicate to virtualbox host. I think  `$ eval "$(docker-machine env default)"` to get environment ready so brings `docker` command available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried windows 10, windows 7 and Mac, just can't communicate with Virtualbox machine, so no docker command is found

This isn't your error.

Your error is that your shell cannot find the `docker` executable. Docker requires two pieces, the server daemon (which is running in docker-machine's VM) and the client.

Make sure you have installed the docker client and that it is available in your $PATH.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I see. I thought we don't need docker client if we are using docker-machine. as I just downloaded `docker-machine` only. I was thinking `$ eval "$(docker-machine env default)"` will bring me to virtualbox environment which enables me to run `docker` command. In this case, I think I can just use `docker-machine ssh default`, then I don't need a client

Comment: Tick this. The answer is `and the client.`

Comment: @olo glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think "docker-machine ssh default" will work fine here. By writing ssh you are creating a secure shell connection to your host and then you can talk to your host.